# PHP imagettftext() - nothing is displaying

Tags: php, gd

Trying to display a font using the GD library. There is indeed an image there, it's just that theres nothing displaying.

PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$font = $_GET['font'];

// Create the image
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($image, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'The Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog';
$font = '/Aller/' . $font;


// Add the text
imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

imagepng($image);
```

HTML:

```
<img src="fontgen.php?font=Aller_Rg.ttf" alt="" />
```

The font resides in fonts/Aller/Aller_Rg.tff

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `$font` variable. From the documentation:

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path.
>
> When using versions of the GD library lower than 2.0.18, a space character, rather than a semicolon, was used as the 'path separator' for different font files. Unintentional use of this feature will result in the warning message: Warning: Could not find/open font. For these affected versions, the only solution is moving the font to a path which does not contain spaces.
>
> In many cases where a font resides in the same directory as the script using it the following trick will alleviate any include problems.

```
<?php
// Set the enviroment variable for GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

// Name the font to be used (note the lack of the .ttf extension)
$font = 'SomeFont';
?>
```

You also said that the font resides in `fonts/Aller/` directory. Whereas, in your script, there is no reference to the `fonts` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The code is all correct except this part

```
$font = '/Aller/' . $font;
```

It tries the absolute path '/Aller/Aller_Rg.tff' not 'Aller/Aller_Rg.tff'

Changing it to `$font = 'Aller/' . $font;` should work.

Also you should check the error log, it should mention `Invalid font filename`

When in doubt remove `header('Content-Type: image/png');` for debugging.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), a beginning slash is expected.

Comment: Depends on the GD library, a beginning slash doesn't work for me (and apparently him too)